# JUnit test results show 0 when test fails, but 1 when test is ok

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I am starting with JUnit tests.

I am trying to write simple test and got the issue.

When test is ok, it is shown in results: 
Tests run: **1**, Failures: **0**, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.008 s

```
@SpringBootTest
public class SampleTest {

    @Test
    public void Test() {
        assertEquals( 1,1, "Fail");
        // assertEquals( 1,0, "Fail"); Should fail and display message
    }
}
```

When I change one 1 to 0, so it should fail:
Tests run: **0**, Failures: **0**, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.008 s
It also doesn't throw the error message which should be thrown.

Am I doing something wrong or it should not be like that? Tried to google but can't find similar issue.

I am using JUnit5. Running tests from IntelliJ Idea - > Maven Projects -> Lifecycle -> Test

**UPDATE:**

I have tried to run it from IntelliJ - all messages shown etc.
Strange that it is not working properly from Maven tests.

**UPDATE 2:**
It may be something about pom.xml config?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>project</name>
    <description>project - server</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <junit-jupiter-api-version>5.0.0-M5</junit-jupiter-api-version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.0.0-M5</junit.jupiter.version>
        <junit.platform.version>1.0.0-M5</junit.platform.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-facebook</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-hibernate5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0.pr1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>22.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter-api-version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0-M4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>surefire-snapshots</id>
            <name>Surefire Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/snapshots/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

Comment: you mean you changed that to `assertEquals(0,0, "fail"); ?

Comment: I am just changing it to assertEquals( 0,1, "Fail");

Comment: Try using wrapper types as  assertEquals( new Integer(0),new Integer(1), "Fail"); and check

Comment: @AvinashReddy - That should not be necessary.

Comment: Won't change anything. If it's 1,1 it's fine and test succeed.

Comment: @AvinashReddy please don't!

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that this shouldn't compile - `org.junit.Assert.assertEquals` takes the string message as the **first** parameter (see http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - No, You're wrong. In JUnit 5 the message is the last argument which makes perfect sense because it's optional

Comment: @MU - Ah fair, I didn't notice you specified 5.

Comment: This is a **ghastly** thing for the makers of JUnit to have done.  Millions of developers all around the world are familiar with putting the message first.  Billions of test cases are currently written that way in JUnit 4.  This makes it really expensive for an organisation to upgrade to JUnit 5, and frankly, they may as well just switch to TestNG.

Comment: You can run Junit4 tests with Junit5 with specified Vintage runner and I think it'll be fine.

Comment: Ooh.  Is it possible OP has done that here?  Might that be the answer to the question?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem. What is the reason it should not be done this way assertEquals( new Integer(0),new Integer(1), "Fail");. As you pointed as please don't

Comment: Because it sacrifices readability for no conceivable gain.  Readability is something programmers should fight for, not just throw carelessly away. And it won't fix OP's problem anyway.

Comment: What happens if you a) drop the `@SpringBootTest` annotation and b) split the two assertions into two methods?

Comment: The problem is you are getting:
"Tests run: 0"
If you can get it to run then it will be failing

Comment: @MartinByers so why it is running when not failing, but not running when failing? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: How do you launch the tests? Via console, gradle, maven or within an IDE?

Comment: Running tests from IntelliJ Idea - > Maven Projects -> Lifecycle -> Test

Comment: Is your `pom.xml` configured to use JUnit 5? Something similar to this example: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/master/junit5-maven-consumer/pom.xml

Comment: I just ran this test with JUnit 5 from IntelliJ and it works as it should.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch just did it a moment before your comment. When running with IntelliJ instead of Maven command - working fine and showing everything.

Comment: well I can run it both with IntelliJ and maven on the command line, both work

Comment: @P.J.Meisch please take a look at my pom.xml - maybe I am missing something?

Comment: See the answer from @Sormuras regarding Maven Surefire 2.19.1 and mixed milestone versions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Maven Surefire Plugin 2.20 is not supported. See https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/809 for details. Roll back to 2.19.1
2. Align the JUnit (Jupiter and Platform) versions through-out the `pom.xml`. There's a mixure of M4 and M5.

> When I change one 1 to 0, so it should fail: Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.008 s It also doesn't throw the error message which should be thrown.

*Tests run: 0* is reported because of the `OutOfMemoryError` produced by the Maven Surefire Plugin 2.20